# Eclipse cannot use UseParallelGC option?

Tags: java, eclipse

After adding

```
-XX:+UseParallelGC
```

to /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini, my Eclipse can no longer start.

- Eclipse 2020-06 for macOS
- macOS 10.14.6

Comment: I don't see why Eclipse specifically wouldn't work with it, what do the logs say?

Comment: *Where* did you add it? It makes a difference.

Comment: Where to find the log?

Comment: Location of the file where I added it is added to the OP now.

Comment: *"Where to find the log?"*  - read https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works after removing `-XX:+UseG1GC`.

Comment: Nice, makes sense, you can't ask Eclipse to use 2 different GC strategies. Just curious,  do you feel or is there a difference using the `ParallelGC`?

Comment: I can't feel any difference at all. Any idea how to measure the possible difference or improvement?